# How to create a hash with set of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following:

```
[[1,1,3], [1,2,3], [2,1,3]
```

I want to be able to take the above, and create a hash

```
 1 => { [1,3], [2,3] }, 2 => {[1,3]}
```

EDIT

Furthermore, I also wanted to add the following:

since the first element in the new array is the month, if I dont have data for the 4th month, it can default to [4,0]

```
 1 => { [1,3], [2,1], [3,4], }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = [[1,1,3], [1,2,3], [2,1,3]]
y = x.map {|a| {a[0]=> [a[1], a[2]]}}
```

**Edit**

Actually my initial solution was wrong, it gives you:

```
[{1=>[1, 3]}, {1=>[2, 3]}, {2=>[1, 3]}]
```

I believe this is closer to what you were looking for:

```
x = [[1,1,3], [1,2,3], [2,1,3]]
h = {}

x.each do |a|
  if h[a[0]].nil?
    h[a[0]] = []
  end
  h[a[0]] << [a[1], a[2]]
end
```

Which gives you a hash of arrays:

```
{1=>[[1, 3], [2, 3]], 2=>[[1, 3]]}
```

Comment: Quick question, in my edit, these numbers are used for calculations using the month... Lets say I don't have April (4) data, how can I force  [4,0]?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Once you have created the hash all you need to do is check `h[4]`, which will be nil, telling you that you don't have April data.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'facets'
xs = [[1,1,3], [1,2,3], [2,1,3]]
xs.map_by { |*ys| [ys.first, ys.drop(1)] }
=> {1=>[[1, 3], [2, 3]], 2=>[[1, 3]]}
```